# How to find mutations related to disease for a protein?

Tags: proteins, pathology, mutations

I have done research on the protein (CYP3A4). I have its function, purpose and diseases (breast cancer, prostate cancer, testicular cancer, lung cancer). I am however having trouble finding the mutations of the protein and how it correlates with the diseases, specifically breast and prostate cancer.

Comment: What is your question? If you want to know more about the protein the way to go is to read papers about it.

Comment: Where do I find such papers

Comment: Does anyone know about my question and can help?

Comment: [Pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed), [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com)... As it is written, your question is just too broad (also unclear because there is no real "question"). Please clarify and narrow it down to focus on a specific issue.

Answer (score 6):

I think I understand what you are asking so I will make a little guide to find what you need: 
**NOTE**  the mutations you are searching for are probably on gene level so you can search your protein on [Uniprot](http://www.uniprot.org/) and then use the gene name to search on [DisGeNET](http://www.disgenet.org/web/DisGeNET/menu/search?1), you typ in the gene you are searching for: 
[image]
Then you hit the search button and this will give you a result like this: 
[image]
You can see that this site uses a sort of [text-mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining), in other words it is searching for the gene name associated with disease in articles. The score is an indication for how good the text-mining "worked". As mentioned in the [manual](http://www.disgenet.org/web/DisGeNET/menu/dbinfo#score):

> We have developed a score to rank the gene-disease associations
>   according to their level of evidence. DisGeNET gene-disease
>   association score takes into account the number and type of sources
>   (level of curation, model organisms), and the number of publications
>   supporting the association. The score ranges from 0 to 1.

Then you have to click the `browse details...` in the down right corner. This will guide you to another summary page like this: 
[image]
(**NOTE** I omitted a lot of rows to avoid huge images in the answer, so there will be more rows in your result). Because you were interested in prostate cancer I will click on Prostatic Neoplasms: 
[image]
You can click on the `3` to obtain the 3 articles where the combination of the CYP3A4 and Prostatic Neoplasms was found. This will give you a list like: 
[image]
As you mentioned in your question

> "where do I find such papers"

You can easily click on the PMID this will guide you to the article, for example the first article:

> CYP3A4 polymorphisms--potential risk factors for breast and prostate
>   cancer: a HuGE review([link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15496535)).

I think this will help you to find the papers related to the protein + disease, you can further read the papers to find mutations which cause these diseases.